# Show for some $f$ differentiable at $x_0\in A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that $\overline{f}$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

For $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ let $\overline{f}:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C},x\mapsto\overline{f(x)}$ be the conjugate function.

Show for some $f$ differentiable at $x_0\in A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that $\overline{f}$ is differentiable at $x_0$ with $\overline{f'}(x)=\overline{f'(x_0)}$.

---

I'm having some trouble understanding this exercise. Now I do suspect that I need to show, technically, that

$$lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{\overline{f}(x)-\overline{f}(x_0)}{x-x_0} = lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{\overline{f(x)-f(x_0)}}{x-x_0}$$

exists. However I'm not even sure what $\overline{f}$ really is supposed to be or how to work with the equation above. The numerator has some complex conjugate, the denominator real numbers—how do I make use of that or in other words, what is $\overline{f(x)-f(x_0)}$ in the first place?

Comment: $\overline{f}$ is defined in the statement of the problem: $\overline{f}(x)=\overline{f(x)}$. The equation that needs to be proven has an inconvenient typesetting. As written, the proof could be $\overline{f'}(x)=\overline{f'(x)}$, by definition of $\overline{\cdot}$. But if written as $(\overline{f})'(x)=\overline{f'(x)}$, then it is more interesting. In that case, we do need to compute ...

Comment: $(\overline{f})'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\overline{f}(x)-\overline{f}(x_0)}{\overline{x}-\overline{x_0}}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\overline{f(x)}-\overline{f(x_0)}}{\overline{x}-\overline{x_0}}=\overline{\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}}=\overline{f'(x_0)}$

Comment: There is yet another problem, that $(\overline{f})'$ needs to be understood as I wrote above, derivative with respect to $\overline{x}$, while $f'$ has to be understood as derivative with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

As stated the result is false. A simple counter-example: $A=\mathbb C,f(z)=z$. $f$ is differentiable at all points but its conjugate is not. Perhaps the question is about derivative as a function of two real variables, not about complex differentiation at all.